# Error while creating a app with react-native init <AppName>: ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a react-native app using "react-native init" 
    but its throwing the below error. I have created apps before but it suddenly started to throw this error when i tried to create a new app

> **ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add'**

I tried to do `npm start`, `react-native start`. and deleted the 
    `node_modules` and re-installed it.

> info Setting up new React Native app in /home/sagar/Desktop/rn- 
>       prac/justTesting
>       info Adding required dependencies
>       ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add'
>       (node:9851) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command 
>       failed: yarn add react@16.8.6
>       at makeError (/home/sagar/Desktop/rn- 
>       prac/justTesting/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
>       at Promise.all.then.arr (/home/sagar/Desktop/rn- 
>       prac/justTesting/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>       (node:9851) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
>       rejection.
>
> This error originated either by throwing inside of an 
>       async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
>       which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
>       (node:9851) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise 
>       rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that 
>       are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero 
>       exit code.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccqcW.png)

Comment: please click on the error link for the image

Comment: package.json
    {
     "name": "justTesting",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: I am having same problem but I am using Windows11 os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3708)

First, run `sudo apt remove cmdtest` before installing yarn with `sudo apt install yarn`
 or

You need to follow the installation instructions on the website https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/ and add a repo first. This will then include the correct yarn, and if a conflict occurs then for correcting run following command:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

I too got a similar error with this("node_modules/execa/index.js") file.
I resolved my error using the 2 commands given below

```sh
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

```sh
yarn global add @react-native-community/cli
```